# Not getting tick mark for drop down in some browser

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, selection

I have a simple HTML program where I created drop down containing couple of items. My problem is when I open my html page in Safari, I get (Right) tick mark but when I open it in other browsers such as Chrome/Firefox so I don't get it.

So, I just want to know is it browser specific issue or something else?

Comment: can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a browser specific issue.

I set up a jsfiddle with a couple lines of code in the HTML box: https://jsfiddle.net/fvgxejed/

```
<select>
 <option>1st option</option>   
 <option>2nd option</option>
 <option>3rd option</option>
</select>
```

and it seems to be working.

I tested it out on Chrome, IE, and Firefox (on Windows), and they all display the right tick mark.